# Handling nested views inside dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-router-extras

We are using `angular-ui-router` for handling nested views in page level and it works fine. but we are not able to display nested views inside dialog. I searched in stackoverflow and not found useful things yet.

I have tried using **ui-router** as well with **ui-roter-extras** using sticky state

**ui-router**

[Example 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2j471?p=preview)

**ui-router with ui-router-extras (sticky state)**

[Example 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/6iL0mq?p=preview)

In the above samples, Check the following road map

```
Click "First Page" > Click "Popup Page" > Click "Child Page1" or "Child Page 2"
```

Child Pages not getting displayed. Anyone have an idea to fix this..or tell me other directions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Absolute named view (putting @ end of the name) is working fine.** Please check the below link for more details.

https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/125

```
  $stateProvider.state('first.popup.child1', {
    url: '/child1',
    views: {
      'child1View@': {
        templateUrl: 'child1.html'
      }
    }
  });


  $stateProvider.state('first.popup.child2', {
    url: '/child2',
    views: {
      'child2View@': {
        templateUrl: 'child2.html'
      }
    }
  });
```